# Reusing code in .module and .inc files

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 7, rdf

I plan to develop a module (say M2) that uses a pre-existing module(M1) as a soft dependency.  In short there are a number of functions that I can reuse from M1 in my module M2...

other than specifying M1 as a dependency in M2's .info file what other steps do I need to take to re-use M1's functions.. also since these aren't classes but functions so how can I inherit them ?

using module_load_include() function only includes the .inc file... but then what about the .module file of M1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If M1 is enabled, the .module file will be included on every page load anyway. And if M1 is a dependancy of M2, M1 will definitely be enabled if M2 is enabled.

It's only the other files (`.inc`, etc.) that might contain extra functionality that you'll need to load explicitly with `module_load_include()`.

Comment: yeah thnx rite, ive just started so my concepts are a bit shaky.. and how can I reuse the functions in the .inc files ? by overriding them or what ?

Comment: and also the in the .module file how can I go about reusing them ?? eg.. if I have some task I just call the function of M1 and pass in the appropriate arguments and get the result..

Comment: There's no such concept as overriding functions in PHP (unless they're part of an abstract class/interface; or they've changed something and I haven't caught up yet!) You'll either need to use the functions as they are, or re-implement them with different names

Comment: so in m2.module  file suppose I call a function m1_somehook_function() then that will be correct ??

Comment: That's fine, yeah, but make sure there's not already a function called `m1_somehook_function()` that's being included in the page...PHP requires function names to be unique

Comment: no what i meant was I am calling a function m1_somehook_function() that has already been declared and defined in m1.module which I am now using as a dependency..so if i just make a call to that function in m2.module file, will it be correct ??

Comment: Ah sorry I get you now...yep that should be fine; if the function is in m1.module, you'll be able to call it from m2.module without any problem